# Don't work button 'Send' for django private chat

Tags: python, html, django

I installed the django private chat package, but the send button does not work. I configured everything properly

settings.py

```
CHAT_WS_SERVER_HOST = 'localhost'
CHAT_WS_SERVER_PORT = 5002
CHAT_WS_SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'ws'
```

template/base.html

```
{% block css %}{% endblock css %}
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
{% block extra_js %}{% endblock extra_js %}
```

in the dialogs.html files I have the exact code from the package.

Comment: This is going to be just guessing. Maybe you can share logging output and relevant logs?

Comment: Looks like django private chat is deprecated. Have you tried the new version: https://pypi.org/project/django-private-chat2/ ?

Comment: Yes, I also tried the new version.

Comment: I'm not mistaken. On the django admin page I can send messages, but not on the page.